# Live Trace VS Image Trace

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2014, image-trace, live-trace

I want to create a sphere with green grass texture , I searched and I wanted to use  [this](http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-create-a-vector-grass-text-effect--vector-5379)  method to create grass texture , but as we know  , In Illustrator CC 2014 , instead of Live trace ,there is Image Trace .
It seems Image Trace has more options
I don't know how to set Image Trace to create details exactly the same.

Live Trace that used in earlier versions

[image: Live Trace that used in earlier versions]

Image Trace in Illustrator 2014

[image: Image Trace in Illustrator 2014]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The `Path Fitting` and `Minimum Area` options from Live Trace are not directly transferable to Image Trace. However, adjusting the `Paths` options will *sort of* adjust things in the same manner.

Comment: Isn't mode color different from mode Gray scale ? if it is then We can't choose Max Colors

Comment: @N93 You can choose `Mode: Greyscale` from that drop down. Did you even look?

Comment: yes Of course I see, I mean If I choose Grey scale , It hasn't colors options  , but its Ok I understood what to do

Comment: The "colors" label is a bit misleading. In Greyscale mode it would mean "shades". Basically it's the number of steps the trace should factor -- either color steps or grey steps.